# What is the outcome of "typeof Enum" inTypescript?

Tags: typescript

I know that an `enum` in Typescript compiles down to an object for runtime.  I wanted to merge two enums `enum EnumOne { ... }; enum EnumTwo { ... }` with Object.assign(). That works.

In doing so, Typescript tells me, that the product of that is `typeof EnumOne & typeof EnumTwo`. So far, so good.

Now, Typescript also lets me know that “*`EnumOne` is not assignable to `typeof EnumOne`*”, which sounds reasonable, but it makes me wonder, what actually does `typeof EnumOne` mean? What is that? I cannot get the Typescript compiler to give me any meaningful information on it.

Comment: `EnumOne` is a type which can hold a specific enum. `typeof EnumOne` is a type which can hold the type of `EnumOne`, or one of its subtypes.

Comment: "... can hold the type of EnumOne, ..." hold the type means: as a union type? Because as a union type would mean EnumOne would be part of "typeof EnumOne", which it is not, as the message suggests. I am still confused :)

Comment: Have you got an [mcve]?

Comment: @jcalz, thanks, that helps.